# Is there a way to take some Javascript code that toggles divs and make it so when i return to that page, the same div is open that was when I left?

Tags: javascript, html, persistence, toggle

Is there a way to take some Javascript code that toggles divs and make it so when I return to that page, the same div is open that was when I left?

I am using this script:

```
(function() { // using an IIFE to prevent polluting the global namespace
    var opened_element = null;

    window.toggle_visibility = function(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (opened_element && opened_element !== e) {
            opened_element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(e.style.display == 'block') {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
        opened_element = e;
    };
}());
```

Comment: Javascript can be used to toggle the visibility of divs, but if you wish to maintain state you will need to write the required information to a cookie or a session.

Answer (score 1):

Any question about HTML that involves the phrase "and maintains that between pages" needs a bit of a reminder about how HTML is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). You will need some form of special variable to keep track of things between pages, and render the page appropriately based on that. Your options include:

- Cookies.
- PHP/Java server "session" variables. (ie, $_SESSION['divShowing'])
- localStorage (Javascript; not supported on older browsers. sessionStorage is also available, if you don't want to maintain between browser sessions)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you may use LocalStorage for saving current opened div (but it will work only in new browsers; if you have to support smth like IE<=8, you should use cookies instead).

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id), opened_element = document.getElementById(localStorage.opened_element);
    if (opened_element && opened_element !== e) {
        opened_element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    localStorage.opened_element = e.id;
};
if (localStorage.opened_element) {
    toggle_visibility(localStorage.opened_element);
}
```